# javascript text doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a simple program "Find the Largest Number". The problem is, I can't display the output of my answer. Is there anything wrong on my code? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Short Lab Activity 1 </title>

<style>
#compute{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="compute">
Input 1st Number: <input type="integer" id="num1" size="20"/> </br></br>
Input 2nd Number: <input type="integer" id="num2" size="20"/> </br></br>
Answer: <input type="integer" id="answer" size="20"/>
</div>
<center><input type="button" id="find" value="Find the Largest" onClick()="find()"/></center>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function find() {
     var numb1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
     var numb2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
     var answer;

     if(numb1 > numb2)
        document.getElementById("answer").value = numb1;
     if(numb2 > numb1)
        document.getElementById("answer").value = numb2;
         }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(numb1 > numb2) { condition } else{ else condition}`

Comment: The equal condition is missed here

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated! Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: This will not help solve your problem but the type='integer' is invalid (the browser will convert this to text). A list of correct types, and their use, can be found at: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/

Answer (score 1):

Change `onClick()="find()"` to `onClick="find()"`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
<input type="button" id="find" value="Find the Largest" onClick()="find()"/>
```

Change it to:

```
<input type="button" id="find" value="Find the Largest" onClick="find()"/>
```

You do not need the parenthesis `()`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistake is that instead of `onClick() = "find()"` it should be  `onclick = "find()"`. .

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using `onclick` in the html. Instead you could use `addEventListener`.

As for modifications to your function, `if` statement could be written like this,

```
if (numb1 > numb2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").value = numb1;
} else if (numb2 > numb1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").value = numb2;
}
```

Now after your function, you can add the event listener like this,

```
var el = document.getElementById("find");
el.addEventListener("find", find, false);
```

You can learn more about the `addEventListener` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).